# Do not hyperlink menu heading

Tags: menus

How do I make a menu entry that's just plain text, not a link?

My kludge workaround is linking to "/", but I'd prefer no link at all.

Comment: You should start accepting answers for your Qs, before expecting someone to answer this Q (33% is normally a draw back for most people).

Comment: [This question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%27menu+placeholder%27) has been asked and answered quite a bit

Comment: If I got more answers like Lyken's, I would!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a dynamic menu you can use a 'Custom Links' and use a # for the URL then click add to menu.

Once it's in the menu, remove the # from the URL in the menu and save the menu.

It'll then be a text only no link item. (you can then add sub menu's that are linked) which is what I use this method for.